# What happened to Worldgrids.org?

Tags: data, metadata, soilgrids

I am working on a manuscript using the gridded soil type data product obtained from worldgrids.org and need to cite the data source. However the domain has expired. Does anyone have any idea what happened, or if the datasets formerly on worldgrids.org are hosted elsewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180810013444/http://worldgrids.org/):

> **ISRIC WorldGrids**
>
> The domain worldgrids.org will be discontinued.
>
> A set of GIS layers of biophysical properties available at:
>
> ```
> ftp://isric.org
> username: gsp
> password: gspisric
> ```
>
> for each territory in the world.
>
> If you can't find what you are looking for, the following links might be useful
>   http://data.isric.org or [www.isric.org](http://www.isric.org).

**Update 2019-02-01:**

Currently working links:

- https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids
  SoilGrids homepage with links to data, usage information, etc.
- https://soilgrids.org
  Slippy map to browse world-wide data.  Datasets can also be downloaded via this interface.
- http://www.isric.org
  ISRIC homepage
- http://data.isric.org/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/search?facet.q=type%2Fdataset
  Individual browsable and searchable datasets
- ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/data/
  Global gridded data
- https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/
  Largely the same data as on the above FTP server.

  > This repository contains a collection of updatable soil property and
  >   class maps of the world at a relatively coarse resolution (1 km, 250 m
  >   etc) produced using automated soil mapping based on Machine Learning.
- [ftp://ftp.isric.org](ftp://ftp.isric.org/)
  Password protected; the posted credentials (`gsp`/`gspisric` or `public`/`public`) don't work
- https://web.archive.org/web/20170512192352/http://worldgrids.org/doku.php
  Archived version of the old site (thanks to markusN for pointing that out).

Comment: Thanks for this. I was also unable to access the FTP site at isric.org, unfortunately. I guess it is also down.

Comment: Try https://web.archive.org/web/20170512192352/http://worldgrids.org/doku.php

Comment: @qdread I've updated the links; you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 3):

The FTP systems access  have been discontinued and please only use the Webdavs

- https://files.isric.org/soilgrids for soilgrids.
- For the GSP  layers use: https://files.isric.org/projects/gsp/ with password `gsp / gspisric`

Please notice that all links are only HTTPS

Webdav can be used as network drive on [windows](https://uvacollab.screenstepslive.com/s/help/m/sitetools/l/611578-how-do-i-set-up-webdav-for-windows-10-or-8) or generic mount [linux](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/09/04/how-to-mount-webdav-share/)

In case of problems please contact ISRIC IT it.isric [at] wur.nl